# ng-bind with AngularJS translate interpolation

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate, ng-bind

I need to render characters such as < and >, which may be included in a user's first or last name. I'm using angular translate to render the name, passing the first and last name as values. However, if the first or last name contains < the value will not be displayed. I think I need to use something like `ng-bind="translation_key | translate | values"` but this is incorrect. How can I use ng-bind with angular translate interpolation? Is this the correct way to go about rendering a translated value that contains chars such as <, >? Thanks.

***Edit**

This almost works but the sanitizer outputs an error.

```
ng-bind="'locales.user_filter' | translate: { first: user.firstName, last: user.lastName }"
```

> Error: [$sanitize:badparse] The sanitizer was unable to parse the following block of html:

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using a filter before passing the values to the translation key.

```
.filter('htmlEntities', function () {
  return function (input) {
    return String(input).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
  };
});


var first = $filter('htmlEntities')(scope.user.firstName);
var last = $filter('htmlEntities')(scope.user.lastName);
scope.displayName = $translate.instant('locales.user_filter', { first: first, last: last });

<td ng-bind-html="displayName"></td>
```